# Docker instance stops without logs

Tags: python, docker

I am rather new to docker so still trying to understand what I am doing.
I basically create a docker file such as follow:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /root/tam
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update && pip3 install numpy && pip3 install pybase64 
CMD ["tam.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

after that I did the following command:
`sudi docker build -t tam .` to create the image, then to run it: `sudo docker run -it tam tam.py`

However, the service stops running after 2 or 3 days, and I do not know how to debug that. Any insights? What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is it deployed on a server that starts/ stops at certain time intervals? If yes, you need to add --restart=always. Or possible memory issue. (Out of memory exception)

Comment: @neilharia7 no it does not starts/stops at certain interval, but I can try that anyway. I just need to add in the dockerfile `RESTART=ALWAYS` ?

Comment: No not in the dockerfile, while running the container add `--restart=always` at the end.